# Template-level subscriptions for different templates

Tags: javascript, templates, search, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm building an app with a database called `Courses`. Users should be able to search for courses using the `search` template and select courses that they want to add. Their selected courses should show up in the `selected` template.

`Courses` right now has two publications: `courses.all` and `courses.search`, the second of which takes a search parameter:

```
Meteor.publish('courses.all', function () {
    return Courses.find({});
});

Meteor.publish('courses.search', function(q) {
    let query = {}, projection = {limit: 10, sort: {dept: 1, courseNo: 1}};

    if (q && q.length > 0) {
        query = {
            $text: {
                $search: q,
            }
        }
    }

  let out = Courses.find(query, projection);
  return out;
});
```

(Note that `courses.search` must take place on the server, since Minimongo doesn't support the `$text` operator yet.)

The `search` template then subscribes to `courses.search` (following this guide: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/simple-search):

```
Template.search.onCreated(function searchOnCreated() {
    this.state = new ReactiveDict();

    let template = Template.instance();
    template.searchQuery = new ReactiveVar();
    template.searching = new ReactiveVar(false);

    this.autorun(() => {            
        this.subscribe('courses.search', template.searchQuery.get(), () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                template.searching.set(false);
                Tracker.flush();
                $(".collapsible").collapsible(); // needed for the UI
            }, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

Then, whenever the search form is submitted, `template.searchQuery` is updated:

```
"submit #search-form" (evt, template) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let value = $("[name=search]").val().trim();
    if (value !== "") {
        template.searchQuery.set(value);
        template.searching.set(true);
    }   else if (value === "") {
        template.searchQuery.set(value);
    }
}
```

Simple enough. Then, inside `schedule`, I subscribe to `courses.all`, and call `Courses.find`, which (I thought) should return results from `courses.all`:

```
courses() {
    let out = Meteor.user().courses.map((course) => {
        return Courses.findOne(course);
    });

    return out;
}
```

The issue is this: any course ID not returned in the search results (i.e., in the output of `courses.search`) is not found in `schedule`'s call to `Courses.findOne`. I know, though, that you can't have two template-level subscriptions for the same template. Is is also the case that you can't have two template-level subscriptions to *different* templates? If so, can anyone suggest a workaround that would let `schedule` see all of the values in Courses, and `search` see only the search results?

(I'm using Meteor 1.4.2.1.)

Comment: One option I'm considering is defining a special `/search?q=query` path, and then letting FlowRouter take care of delivering `courses.all` to `schedule` and `courses.search` to `search`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with template-level subscriptions.

Comment: inside your onCreated(), you have an autorun, and inside of that you have this.subscribe(). I'm not sure that "this" refers to your template in that context. Maybe create a "let self = this" outside of there and try "self.subscribe()".

Comment: The other thing i would do is get some kind of client-side minimongo inspection tool and see if your client is getting published to it the data you think you're getting. i think i understand what you're doing in your helper (i.e. your user object has courses on it, and you want to get only those courses assigned to that user), but i would eliminate that code as a problem by inspecting the minimongo data directly.

Comment: Where do you subscribe to `courses.all`?

Comment: Your schedule template needs to subscribe to `courses.all` - i.e. you should have two templates, each with a distinct subscription.

Comment: @Khang I subscribe to `courses.all` inside the `schedule` template `onCreated` function.

Comment: @MichelFloyd So my `schedule` and `search` templates are completely separate -- they're children of the same parent, I guess, but nothing more than that -- and yet if I subscribe to `courses.all` inside `schedule` the results still show up inside `courses.search`. Does Minimongo just create one massive database on the client for all results? Or does it separate by template?

Comment: minimongo contains the union of all subscriptions. Each template should execute the requisite search filter on minimongo. Never assume minimongo has only what you need.

Comment: @MichelFloyd okay, that explains a lot. So normally, I'd do `Courses.find({active: true})` or something inside `schedule`, and `Courses.find({query: foo})` (by which I of course mean a real search operator), but the problem is that I do a `$text` search, which MM doesn't support. How would you recommend that I disambiguate the results of `Courses.find()`? Or is there a better way to do search?

Comment: Ah ok, a couple possibilities. Either stop the other subscriptions so that the irrelevant data gets flushed or [transform](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) your cursor in your publication to tag each document with something that you can query for on the client.